# Box.com integration for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, box-api, box, cloud-storage

Does somebody know if there is a plugin for WordPress that can integrate the Box.com cloud service into a page/post? I am looking for a way to show my files from Box.com directly on a page in a sort of file browser.

I know that there are some plugins around that can do it for Dropbox or Google Drive. But I don't want to switch, so it would be nice if I can use my Box.com account.

Has somebody found a similar plugin for Box.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at leveraging [Box Embed](https://developers.box.com/box-embed/) or the [Box File Picker](https://developers.box.com/the-box-file-picker/)?

Either of these will give you a small code snippet to embed Box into your site.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer! I also found [Lets-Box](http://codecanyon.net/item/letsbox-box-plugin-for-wordpress/8204640), a plugin that integrates into the MCE editor of the WordPress system. I think that one is easier to use in my case, but I will see what fits best.